# I can't inflate menu on action bar on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-menu

I'm having trouble inflating the toolbar menu. I have tried everything but I have not succeeded

```
toolbar_layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


toolbar_menu

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>


fragment

    toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    }
```

No error messages, just don't word. Only show the toolbar but not the search menu

Android
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28

Answer (score 0):

problem is here

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
}
```

You have to use it like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Hi!. Thanks for answering. I have tried the way you recommend and the result is the same :(